# Automatic pet feeder with a simple menu type keypad

Tags: arduino-uno, keypad

this is the sample code where the user enters A to set the number of times the pet needs to be fed. When I click A on the keypad it asks for the user to set the number. However, the keypad still somehow saves the input of A that is initially pressed. I want the system to ask for another input. How would I clear the memory of the keypad?
Here is the code attached

```
    /* Hello Wokwi! */
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
const int ROW_NUM    = 4; // four rows
const int COLUMN_NUM = 4; // four columns
char keys[ROW_NUM][COLUMN_NUM] = {
  {'1','2','3', 'A'},
  {'4','5','6', 'B'},
  {'7','8','9', 'C'},
  {'*','0','#', 'D'}
};
int col = 0, row =0;
byte pin_rows[ROW_NUM] = {10,9,8,7};      // connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte pin_column[COLUMN_NUM] = {6,5,4,3}; // connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); // I2C address 0x27, 16 column and 2 rows
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), pin_rows, pin_column, ROW_NUM, COLUMN_NUM );

void setup () {

  lcd.init(); // initialize the lcd
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(col,row); // move cursor to   (cursorColumn, 0)
  lcd.print("HI OWNER");
  delay(3000);
}
int h1,h2,hf1,min1,min2,minf1;
int numfed,setnofeed=0;

void loop() {
  
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if(!key){
    displaytime();
  }

  switch(key){
    case 'A': 
      lcd.setCursor(col,row);
    lcd.print("SET NO. OF");
    lcd.setCursor(col,1);
    lcd.print("FEEDING TIMES");
    delay(3000);

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(col,row);
    lcd.print("MAX 5 MIN 2");
    col=0;
    lcd.setCursor(col,1);
    if (col==0&&setnofeed==0){
      numfed=key-48;
      lcd.print(numfed);
      delay(1000);
      col=1;
    }
    else if(col==1){
    lcd.setCursor(col,1);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("NO. OF FEEDING");
    lcd.setCursor(col,1);
    lcd.print("SET");
    delay(2000);
    setnofeed=1;
    }
   
    break;


  }
  
}
void displaytime(){

      lcd.setCursor(0,0); // move cursor to   (cursorColumn, 0)
    lcd.print("Time now:");
}
```

Comment: where is the `keypad memory`?

Comment: don't be in a rush to do everything when `A` is pressed ... display the menu only, nothing else

Comment: What should I do instead? Are there any proposed solutions?

Comment: start by describing the program behavior, on paper,  in great detail ... a very detailed description translates into code almost directly ... anyway, you already have code that runs when `A` is pressed ... reduce it to display the menu only ... add code that runs when a numeric key is pressed ... add a variable to the program that keeps track of which menu is displayed